# Optional return in delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have a delegate method inside my cell which is called when i click approve button inside the cell.

Now i want this delegate method to have return type Bool which i will use to update UI in my cell.

```
optional func didTapApproveButton(indexpath: NSIndexPath ) -> Bool
```

here is the delegate method.
I Want to keep the return type as optional as i will make a webservice call inside the method in the VC and based on the response i will return true or false.

How to keep that return BOOL as optional

EDIT

This is how i am using the method inside VC

```
func didTapApproveButton(indexpath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool? {
        let user = self.dataCtlr.arrayOfUsers[indexpath.row];

        if(Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()){
            self.dataCtlr.approveRejectUser(true, forUser: user, onSuccess: { (shouldRefreshView) in
                   return true
                }, onFailure: { (result) in

                    return false
            });
        }
        else{

            UserDefaultsManager.sharedInstance.addApproveReject((user.id)!, isApproved: true);
            return true

        }
        return nil
    }
```

Now the return true or false is not returning to the cell so that i can update the cell.

PS: I have update the protocol to swift implementation  like

```
 protocol PendingRequestsTableViewCellDelegate{
     func didTapApproveButton(indexpath: NSIndexPath ) -> Bool?
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `func didTapApproveButton(indexpath: NSIndexPath ) -> Bool?` ?

Comment: Error : Method cannot be member of @objc protocol

Comment: You can use optional delegate in swift if you create an extension for the protocol, so can remove the `optional`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can't use `Bool?` because your protocol is @objc. So you will not be able to use swift specific abilities like optional values.

I would recommend you to remove that `@obj-c` and `Optional` method
    protocol CellDelegate { 
       func didTapApproveButton(indexpath: IndexPath ) -> Bool?
    }

Comment: Updated it , still a new problem i have edited it inside the question

Answer (score 0):

`optional` keyword does not apply to `Optional` type. If you want to mark returning value type as `optional` you should use question mark:

```
func didTapApproveButton(indexpath: NSIndexPath ) -> Bool?
```

FIY `optional` keyword is used for marking method in protocol as not mandatory for implementation. For some reason in your custom protocols you cannot use this keyword.